# Selecting extra fields based on SQL MIN()

Tags: mysql, sql, min

When using the SQL MIN() function, I want to select any additional fields that match the MIN row. Following query returns the correct MIN(sellPrice) but doest not match the correct row in the product_price table. How can I achieve this?

```
SELECT p.*, MIN(pp.sellPrice) AS sellPrice, pp.* FROM `product` AS p
LEFT JOIN `product_price_group` AS ppg ON p.`id` = ppg.`productId`
LEFT JOIN `product_price` AS pp ON ppg.`id` = pp.`priceGroupId`
WHERE p.`active` = 1 AND p.id = 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by `match the correct row in the product_price table.`?  Are you trying to join on the min price or something?  I'm actually kind of suprised that this SQL even works since you don't have a `GROUP BY` clause....

Comment: Yes indeed I'm trying to join on the min price, I want the other fields that belong to the min sell price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By some suggestions I used the GROUP BY attribute and following query is working correctly if I want the lowest sellPrice for a certain product:

```
SELECT p.*, MIN(pp.sellPrice) AS sellPrice, pp.quantity, pp.`priceGroupId`
FROM `product` AS p
LEFT JOIN `product_price_group` AS ppg ON ppg.productId = p.`id`
LEFT JOIN `product_price` AS pp ON pp.priceGroupId = ppg.`id`
WHERE p.`active` = 1 AND  p.id = 1 AND pp.sellPrice IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY pp.id;
```

For all products:

```
SELECT p.*, MIN(pp.sellPrice) AS sellPrice, pp.quantity, pp.`priceGroupId`
FROM `product` AS p
LEFT JOIN `product_price_group` AS ppg ON ppg.productId = p.`id`
LEFT JOIN `product_price` AS pp ON pp.priceGroupId = ppg.`id`
WHERE p.`active` = 1 AND pp.sellPrice IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY pp.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are all the rows where there ISN'T a lower price:

```
SELECT p.*, pp.sellPrice AS sellPrice, pp.* FROM `product` AS p
LEFT JOIN `product_price_group` AS ppg ON p.`id` = ppg.`productId`
LEFT JOIN `product_price` AS pp ON ppg.`id` = pp.`priceGroupId`
WHERE p.`active` = 1 AND p.id = 1
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_price AS pp2
       WHERE pp2.productId = pp.productId AND pp2.sellPrice < pp.sellPrice)
GROUP BY productId;
```

I'm guessing a little on what keys are involved. The idea is to have the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` look for any relevant rows with lower prices. This way MySQL will include in your results only rows where it couldn't find such a "lower price" match.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the minimum sellPrice **for all products** or **for every product**?

**for all products**

```
SELECT p.*
     , pp.sellPrice
     , pp.*
FROM product AS p
LEFT JOIN product_price_group AS ppg
  ON p.id = ppg.productId
LEFT JOIN product_price AS pp
  ON ppg.id = pp.priceGroupId
WHERE p.active = 1
  AND p.id = 1
  AND pp.sellPrice =
    ( SELECT MIN(pp.sellPrice)
      FROM product_price
    )
```

**for every product**

```
SELECT p.*
     , pp.sellPrice
     , pp.*
FROM product AS p
LEFT JOIN product_price_group AS ppg
  ON p.id = ppg.productId
LEFT JOIN product_price AS pp
  ON ppg.id = pp.priceGroupId
JOIN
  ( SELECT priceGroupId
         , pp.MIN(pp.sellPrice) AS sellPrice
    FROM product_price
    GROUP BY priceGroupId
  ) AS ppmin
  ON  ppmin.priceGroupId = pp.priceGroupId
  AND ppmin.sellPrice = sellPrice
WHERE p.active = 1
  AND p.id = 1
```